# PHP Laravel using where on tables included using with

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bit of experience with Laravel but I am in no way a pro.

I have this query:

```
$email_stats = User::with(['identities.sessions.device' => function($q) use ($venue_filter) {
    $q->where('venue_id', $venue_filter);
}])->where('id', $user_id)->first();
```

This query is doing the where on the device table, is there a way to do it on the identities table as well as including the sessions and device table.

Basically what I am trying to do is if the identities table has information which I don't want, I dont want to get that information or the information from the 2 tables below it.

This query works but doesnt get the information from the other 2 tables:

```
$email_stats = User::with(['identities' => function($q) use ($venue_filter) {
    $q->where('venue_id', $venue_filter);
}])->where('id', $user_id)->first();
```

That is now running the where on the identities table but doesn't get the other 2 tables which I also need

Comment: You can send an array of table to User::with, just send the other tables you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$email_stats = User::with(['identities' => function($q) use ($venue_filter) {
    $q->with('sessions.device')->where('venue_id', $venue_filter);
}])->where('id', $user_id)->first();
```